# form_open() not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I am trying to build a simple form in CodeIgniter. My VIEW 'input_view.php' is:

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo "$base/$css"?>">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <?php $this->load->view('books_header'); ?>
        </div>

        <div id="menu">
            <?php $this->load->view('books_menu'); ?>
        </div>
        <?php //echo $title; ?>
        <?php echo form_open('books/input'); ?>

            <?php echo $title; ?>
            <?php echo form_input('title'); ?>;

            <?php echo $author; ?>
            <?php echo form_input('author'); ?>

            <?php echo $publisher; ?>
            <?php echo form_input('publisher'); ?>

            <?php echo $year; ?>
            <?php echo form_dropdown('year',$years); ?>

            <?php echo $available; ?>
            <?php echo form_checkbox('available','yes',TRUE); ?>

            <?php echo $summery; ?>
            <?php echo form_textarea('summery'); ?>

            <?php echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Submit'); ?>

    <?php echo form_close(); ?>


        <div id="footer">
            <?php $this->load->view('books_footer'); ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I tried `http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/books/input`, it does not show the  form, instead shows page upto `menu`. Whats the problem here?

Comment: I am having the same issue even I added $this->load->helper('form'); but I can see in html there no form tags are added in html
Not sure what I am missing.....??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you load form helper in your controller where you call your simple form view?????

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

Comment: Ok.Thank you Vinoth..I missed that.

Answer (score 3):

You must load helper file form for form usage on codigniter like this.

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [CodeIgniter User Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html), you must load form helper before do it like this

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

You may put that syntax on your Controller or at top of your View before you use form_open, form_input or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

in view page

or autoload the file go to application/config/autoload

there you will find

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('');

$autoload['helper'] = array('form'); 

//input from helper it will allow in both view and controller page
```