# calling form_open using a button in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to call a method in my controller class at a button press. want to know how this should be corrected. or is there any other reason that this won't work.

```
    <?php echo form_open('form/SearchUser');?>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
    <?php echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: do you want to call a controller function or form_open?

Comment: Methods in controller are executed at server side, i.e. PHP. Actions such as click, hover on buttons and other HTML elements happen in client side, i.e in client's browser. So you have to capture the client side events and send to server via AJAX if you want to call the method in controller without page refresh.

Comment: Upon seeing your code, I feel like you are trying to implement search form submitting to the method in the controller. If my assumption is right, why not you submit the form to the method in controller with the `action` attribute?

Comment: perhaps you are looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118170/form-open-not-working-in-codeigniter
hope that helps